# DNS and Whois problem

Tags: dns, whois, amazon-ec2, route53

I have encountered a problem or atleast that's what I think, I have recently started an ec2 instance and I changed my A records at Godaddy to point to my new elastic ip and it worked fine and then I signed up to Route 53 and changed the name servers at Godaddy and imported the DNS zone file to Route 53 and it all worked fine, but for some reason when I do whois search for my domain I get Godaddy's ip address, but my site loads fine.

Here is the link for whois records: http://goo.gl/a3z0MI

The reason this question aries in my mind is because I have seen other site's whois with ec2 and route 53 and they seem to be normal here is the example: http://goo.gl/lPE8OY

Thanks in advance

Ankit Yadav

Comment: How long has it been since the change? Officially, it could take up to 48 hours to propagate. Generally, it does not take that long.

Comment: its been 8 hours!

Comment: Patience is a virtue

Comment: Hi @ankityadavuk it's perfectly normal and should resolve after 24-48 hours free feel to vote re-open if the issue doesn't resolve itself.

Answer (score 2):

You are checking your DNS records by using Who.is. A big problem with this is that Who.is does not always perform a Whois lookup or DNS record check live, in real time. They also appear to cache Whois data and DNS data for an unspecified amount of time.

To check your DNS records in real time, you'd want to use `dig` from the command prompt (if you have this tool available). Specifically, the `+trace` option so it will trace the DNS records from the root and not pull any cached information from your local DNS resolvers.

For example:

```
dig +trace hotelsindie.com
```

Alternatively, I have built [GWhois.org](https://gwhois.org/) which will perform both a Whois lookup and DNS record in real time without relying on any caching, so it is much more reliable than Who.is.

https://gwhois.org/hotelsindie.com+dns

[image: screenshot]